# Android Thread Button sleep

Tags: android, multithreading, button, click, handler

For my project, I am trying to execute a Method every 10 seconds when I click a button "A"
and it should stop when I click the button again (kind of on/off).

this is what i reached :-/ :

```
  ButtonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

                        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                         public void run() { 
                             showCurrentLocation();
                                Methodexecute();

                         } 
                    }, 10000); 
                }

                    }
        });
```

How can I repeat executing this method every 10 seconds until the button is clicked again?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a Timer with a TimerTask, scheduling it every 10 seconds.
I hope this will work:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //insert your methods here
        }
    };

    boolean taskIsRunning = false;
    if(taskIsRunning){
        timer.cancel();
        taskIsRunning = false;
    } else {            
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);
        taskIsRunning = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
handler = new Handler();
ButtonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() {
                     if(taskIsRunning){
                         showCurrentLocation();
                         Methodexecute();
                         handler.postDelayed(this,10000);
                     }
                 } 
            }, 10000); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick method you can also toggle the timer task like so:

```
...
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
     ...
     toggleTask();
     ...
}
...
```

and then, from Jonathan's code, something like

```
boolean taskIsRunning = false;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //insert your methods here
    }
};
private void toggleTask() {
    if(taskIsRunning){
        timer.cancel();
        taskIsRunning = false;
    } else {  
        timer = new Timer()          
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);
        taskIsRunning = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,but when i cancel the Timer,i get an error when i restart it again :/

Comment: Ah... yes, it looks like you need to create a new instance after you have cancelled it. I've edited the above code. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel() for reference.